Derivative of Lebesgue integral with indicator functions
Suppose we have a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$.
I want to take the derivative of
$$
W\left(x\right)\equiv\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{1}\left\{ \omega\in R\left(x\right)\right\} f\left(x,\omega\right)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)+\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{1}\left\{ \omega\not\in R\left(x\right)\right\} g\left(x,\omega\right)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
$$
where
$$
f:\mathcal{X}\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\qquad g:\mathcal{X}\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\qquad\mathcal{X}\text{ is an open subset of }\mathbb{R}
$$
If $R(x)$ was just a nice interval (say $\Omega=[0,1]$, $R\left(x\right)=[0,x]$),
then I would apply Leibniz rule. But I am not sure how to proceed
in the general case stated above. Any help or references would be very appreciated!
